# How to debug and step into npm modules that were written in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, npm

An npm module is behaving in an unexpected way and I would like to debug it by setting breakpoints or insert "debugger" statements.

The problem is this npm module was written in TypeScript and the npm module that I have is in the form of transpiled Javascript.

How do I get npm to download the original TypeScript code so I can debug that version of the code instead of transpiled JavaScript?